# Angular2 : Ajax form data return null

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, formbuilder

I'm trying to set a dynamic form in Angular2.
So, in my ngOnInit function, I made a Ajax request to get a JSON with form data.
Like this :

```
export class CustomerEditComponent{
  private customer : Customer = new Customer();
  private customerForm;

  constructor(private _CustomersService: CustomersService, private _routeParams: RouteParams, private _fb: FormBuilder){
    this.customerForm = _fb.group({
      name: [],
      job: [],
      arrival_date: []
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._CustomersService.getById(id).subscribe(res => {
      this.customer = res;
    });
  }

  onSubmit(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

So, at the component construct, 'customer' is equals to a newest one. (all properties are empty). But just after, we set value to every properties.

No problem for that, my input has the correct values.

But, if I submit my form, the form value is equals to :

```
Object {name: null, job: null, arrival_date: null}
```

(But the form in the view is correctly populate).

Here my form (condensed) :

```
<form [ngFormModel]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(customerForm.value)">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.name">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.job">
  <input md-input type="date" [(value)]="customer.arrival_date">

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I use [(value)] cause ng2-material package. (I already try with ngControl).

I think my code is 'wrong' about this feature, but I dunno where.

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

I have found the answer !
With ng2-material, we need to set [(value)] and [(ngModel)] together on every input like this :

```
<form [ngFormModel]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(customerForm)">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.name" [(ngModel)]="customer.name">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.job" [(ngModel)]="customer.job">
  <input md-input type="date" [(value)]="customer.arrival_date" [(ngModel)]="customer.arrival_date">

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

[(value)] is used by ng2-material to set the value 'on front'.

Comment: Isn't the `implements OnInit` missing in your class declaration? `export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit` ?

Comment: In my current version (2.0.0-beta.2), we don't need to implements OnInit (It works without).

Comment: Oh okay, wasn't aware of that in `beta.2` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you didn't associate your form inputs with their controllers within the `ngFormControl` directive in your template. You should refactor that way:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(customerForm.value)">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.name" 
     ngFormControl="name">
  <input md-input [(value)]="customer.job"
     ngFormControl="job">
  <input md-input type="date" [(value)]="customer.arrival_date"
     ngFormControl="arrival_date">

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

See this link from ng2-material samples: https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/blob/master/examples/components/input/form_builder.html

Otherwise why don't you use the `customer` object instead of the `customerForm.value` one?

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hmm. I have added ngFormControl on all inputs, but the result is the same. Null on every properties,if I don't change input content.
And you've right about my customerForm.value, I now use customerForm (to get validation errors and more).

Comment: Why don't you use the `customer` object as parameter of your `onSubmit` method? It should contain the customer data ;-)

Comment: Oh I see your problem. Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]`. Controllers are linked with `ngModel`...

Comment: I also see that you apply a directive on your input (see `md-input`)... What does it aim for?

Comment: I changed my onSubmit param to pass customerForm instead of value of him. When I use ngModel, it give the same result (null). [(value)] is used in ng2-material package (and md-input directive) too.

Comment: I had a look at the samples of ng2-material (https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/blob/master/examples/components/input/form_builder.html). I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Hello Thierry, I have test with [(value)] and [(ngModel)] together on every input and it works perfectly. I edit my post to set the answer. Thanks for you help ;)